# GWT Request Factory. Where to put Proxies?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have multimodule maven project. Root Module: `parent` contain: `server`, `shared`, `client` submodules.

I wonder where in that structure should I put `Proxy classes`? Now I have them in `client` module, but I would like to put them into `shared` module.

Please give me your thought about that. Is this make any sens. I am asking, cause I saw diferent versions.

Here is my proxy class:

```
package pl.derp.web.proxy;


import java.util.List;

import pl.derp.server.entity.User;

import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ProxyFor;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ValueProxy;

@ProxyFor(value = User.class)
public interface UserProxy extends EntityProxy {
  public String getName();
  public void setName( String name );

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about Proxy interfaces, annotated with @ProxyFor? They are not used server-side, so why put them in the shared package, intended for types used in both client and server?

Comment: Yes, the proxy interfaces. Thanks.

Comment: @boris-brudnoy This is wrong, they *are* used server-side.

Comment: Where exactly they are used in `server` side? Proxies are representation of `server's Domain objects` in the `client` side? Proxies uses annotation `@ProxyFor(value =  DomainObject.class)` to declare of what class representation they are, but there is no strictly usage of `Proxies` in `server` as far I know. 
On the other hand, `Proxies` are `DTO- Data Transfer Objects`, and they are shared by `server` and `client` side.

Please give some example.

Comment: @masterdany88 everywhere. One example: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.7.0/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/ServiceLayer.java See the parameters or return types expressed as `Class<? extends RequestContext>` or `Class<? extends BaseProxy>`. The classes **need** to be there.

Comment: In gwt official there is no info about that. And see [here](http://cleancodematters.com/2011/06/04/tutorial-gwt-request-factory-part-i/). So this is not so obvious. But thanks. I will try to rebuild my maven project for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Proxy interfaces need to be available to the client (browser) and server. So they need to be somewhere that both can see the source and classes.

Although your server side source will not reference them directly it is used by the server side part of the build and runtime.

The client source code uses them heavily for your domain code and in the generated plumbing.

We have a web client module that is split in to server/shared/client packages. Having a different module should be OK but I think your shared module will need to export the source.

Comment: Can You help me to write correct maven multimodule project? [Here is my question on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889549/maven-multi-module-project-consist-of-parent-client-shared-server-how-to/32897469#32897469) I've tried to move my `Proxies` into `shared` module, but I've ran into `dependecies cycle`