# Multi module project. Consist of : parent module and submodules: client, shared, server. How to?

Tags: java, build

I would like to have multimodule project of web app. There is `parent` module that content 3 submodules:

`client`, `shared`, `server`.

I would like to build that with maven.

I would like to `client` could access: `server` and `shared` modules code.

I would like to `shared` could access: `server` modules code.

Dependencies that I wonna achieve

```
client -> shared -> server
client -> server
```

Can it be build with maven?

Here are my current poms:

parent:

```
<modules>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>shared</module>
    <module>client</module>
</modules>
```

client:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

shared have no dependencies

server:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

Edit

I would like to have my `shared` module had access to `server` module code, but when I add dependencies to `server` module inside `shared` module, I am getting an error about cycle dependencies and can not build project. My question is how to prepare poms in all submodules to achieve this? As You can see `shared` module doesn't have any dependencies now. –

Comment: Your setup looks right, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Make the appropriate dependencies between the modules and that's it...Yeah and what is the question?

Comment: I would like to have my `shared` module had access to `server` module code, but when I add dependencies to `server` module inside `shared` module, I am getting an error about `cycle dependencies` and can not build project. My question is how to prepare poms in all submodules to achieve this? As You can see `shared` module doesnt have any dependencies now.

Comment: Why do you want to split the shared and client modules in two for the proxies? I think splitting like this can make sense for java logic etc that you want to share between client and server. However, the proxies are for communication so only of interest to the servlet/web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd tend to try and make life simpler and just have two modules (for model, proxies and client code).

e.g.

```
model (maven project)
webclient (maven project)
    shared (package)
    server (package)
    client (package)
```

I'm not totally sure you can do it with three modules because of the cross dependencies.

FWIW we have modules for database, model and client (gwt web client) as that splits the main concerns and keeps the dependencies sane.

Answer (score 0):

Free from maven context there is a cyclic dependency problem in your architecture.
No two modules can depend each other because in that case you can't build them. What you can do is creating another module may be named like "real-shared-module" and both shared and server modules depend to that or you really rearrange your shared module so that it doesn't depend any module other modules and other modules depends to it.

Comment: Can You give for that an example with list of modules and theirs dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

As I know dependencies are transitive

So:

client:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

server:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: So If `client` has access to `server`, and `server` has access to `shared`, it means that the `client` has access to `shared` too?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, cause I cannot access `server` classes from inside of `shared` module. I am getting an error: `Entity cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: The shared/proxy code needs to see the server code so I don't think this will work.